# How might one go about implementing a forward index in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, indexing

I am looking to implement a simple forward indexer in PHP. Yes I do understand that PHP is hardly the best tool for the task, but I want to do it anyway. The rationale behind it is simple: I want one, and in PHP.

Let us make a few basic assumptions:

1. The entire Interweb consists of
   about five thousand HTML and/or
   plain-text documents. Each document resides within a particular domain **(UID)**. No other proprietary/arcane formats exist in our imaginary cavemanesque Interweb.
2. The result of our awesome PHP-based forward indexing algorithm should be along the lines of:

   UID1 -> index.html -> helen,she,was,champion,with,freckles

   UID1 -> foo.html -> chicken,farmers,go,home,eat,sheep

   UID2 -> blah.html -> next,week,on,badgerwatch

   UID2 -> gah.txt -> one,one,and,one,is,not,numberwang

Ideally, I would love to see solutions that take into account, even at their most elementary, the concepts of tokenization/word boundary disambiguation/part-of-speech-tagging.
Of course, I do realise this is wishful thinking, and therefore will humble any worthy attempts at parsing said imaginary documents by:

1. Extracting the real textual content stuff within the document
   as a list of words in the order in
   which they are presented.
2. All the while, ignoring any garbage
   such as `<script>` and `<html>`
   tags to compute a list of UIDs (which could be, for instance, a domain) followed by document name (the resource within the domain) and finally the list of words for that document. I do realise that HTML tags play an important role in the semantic placement of text within a document, but at this stage I **do not care**.
3. Bear in mind a solution that can build the list
   of words WHILE reading the document
   is cooler that one which needs to
   read in the whole document first.

At this stage, I do not care about the wheres or hows of storage. Even a rudimentary set of 'print' statements will suffice.

Thanks in advance, hope this was clear enough.

Comment: Is this your homework? Looks like you just want a simple file parser..

Comment: +1 +1 +1 +1... that's numberwang

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You do somthing like

```
$p = new Simple_dom_parser();
$p->load("www.page.com");
$p->find("body")->plaintext;
```

And that will give you all the text.
Want to iterate over just the links

```
foreach ($p->find("a") as $link)
{
    echo $link->innerText;
}
```

It is very usefull and powerfull.
Check it out.

Comment: quick question: do we remove entries in the forward index after we have consumed and turned it into inverted index?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think I'm totally clear on what you're trying to do, but you can get a simple result fairly easily:

1. Run the page through [Tidy](http://php.net/tidy) ([a good introduction](http://devzone.zend.com/article/761-Tidying-up-your-HTML-with-PHP-5)) to make sure it's going to have valid HTML.
2. Throw away everything before (and including) `<body>`.
3. Step through the document one character at a time.

   1. If the character is a '<', don't do anything with the following characters until you see a '>' (skips HTML)
   2. If the character is a "word character" (alphanumeric, hyphen, possibly more) append it to the "current word".
   3. If the character is a "non-word character" (punctuation, space, possibly more), add the "current word" to the word list in the forward index, and clear the "current word".
4. Do the above until you hit `</body>`.

That's really about it, you might have to add in some exceptions for handling things like `<script>` tags (you don't want to consider javascript to be words that should be indexed), but that should give you a basic forward index.