# Making an index for a search by PHP

Tags: php, regex, search, automata

**How can you search only unique words with PHP** such that I can learn the basics in making the search?

I have had a few problems in making a multidimensional array for questions.

My first [unsuccessful attempt](http://dpaste.com/84178/) is the following.

## #1

```
$result = pg_query_params ( $dbconn, 
    "SELECT question_id, body
    FROM questions",
    array () 
);

while ( $row = pg_fetch_array ( $result ) ) {
    $question_body [ $row['question_id'] ] ['body'] = $row['body'];
    $question_index = explode ( " ", $question_body[ $row['question_id'] ] ['body'] ); 
    $question_index = array_unique ( $question_index ); 
}                                                                                                   
var_dump( $question_index );
```

The problem with this code is that it combines the words in each question.
It seems that I cannot use `explode`, since it seems to make only a single dimensional array.

I also run the following code trying to get question_id [unsuccessfully](http://dpaste.com/84177/).

## #2

```
while ( $row = pg_fetch_array ( $result ) ) {
    $question_body [ $row['question_id'] ] ['body'] = $row['body'];
    $question_index[ $row['question_id'] ] = explode ( " ", $question_body[ $row['question_id'] ] ['body'] );
    $question_index[ $row['question_id'] ]= array_unique ( $question_index );
}
var_dump( $question_index );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and take a look at [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html).

Comment: This sounds promising. However, I would like to first get the easiest search work by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `str_replace` can accept an array of values as the needle. For example,

```
$body = str_replace(array(',', '.'), '', $body);
```

replaces *any* instance of an element in the array with an empty string.

Alternatively, I'd suggest looking at some pre-built search and indexing libraries. It's a *very* hard area to get right from scratch and you're much more likely to get reliable results using an already-polished indexing and searching algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a good idea to first extract all the textual (non-markup) content from the pages by using a DOM parser. See this:

[How might one go about implementing a forward index in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795512/how-might-one-go-about-implementing-a-forward-index-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to use Postgres commands such as `LIKE` for search.
It has been much easier for me to make the data manipulation at DB than at PHP.